# MATLAB: Background color of Text in GUI

Tags: matlab, user-interface, highlight

I want to use GUI (or directly the Command Windows) in MATLAB, which displays text. The text contain a few highlighted parts (which are changed during runtime), like this:

[image]

Is there any way I can do something liek that with MATLAB?

Comment: Is this help? http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/rich-matlab-editbox-contents

Comment: You can look for TeX command working like `\color` in Matlab command `text(X,Y,'Text with {\color{red}red} text')`. I'd recommend using `'interpreter','latex'` to have everything properly aligned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For command window you could try [cprintf](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/24093-cprintf-display-formatted-colored-text-in-the-command-window).

For displaying in a GUI you can use [html formatting](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/html-support-in-matlab-uicomponents) - going down this route you may find [str2html](http://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/46755-str2html) useful.

Comment: great, using html seems to be the perfect solution. thanks for creating that nice possibility for the GUI :-)